# Using BC License Plates in Alberta

Tags: license-plates, alberta

I moved permanently to Alberta from BC.  I now have Alberta driver's license and Alberta license plate.  Can I continue using my BC license plate?

Answer (score 1):

It probably ceased to be proper to use your BC plate no later than the time at which you got the Alberta plate. The Alberta registration supersedes the BC registration. It may have been improper earlier than that, but since nothing has happened so far, it is moot point.